# How to select min when rn = 2

Tags: sql

I have a db table:

```
select SiteName, LastName, Id, Type, StartDate, StartTime, Duration, RN
```

from mytable

```
SiteName    LastName    Id      Type    StartDate   StartTime   Duration    RN
--------    --------    --      ----    ---------   ---------   --------    --  
PK          Jones       284     iov     20171026    830         5           1
PK          Jones       284     iov     20171026    845         5           2
PK          Jones       284     iov     20171113    740         5           1
PK          Jones       284     iov     20171113    845         5           2
PK          Jones       284     iov     20171114    855         5           1
PK          Jones       284     iov     20171201    640         5           1
PK          Jones       284     iov     20171201    845         5           2
PK          Jones       284     iov     20171206    840         5           1
PK          Jones       284     iov     20171206    845         5           2
PK          Jones       284     iov     20171208    855         5           1
PK          Jones       284     iov     20171214    840         5           1
PK          Jones       284     iov     20171214    845         5           2
PK          Jones       284     iov     20171215    840         5           1
PK          Jones       284     iov     20171215    845         5           2
PK          Jones       284     iov     20171222    840         5           1
```

My query gives me these results:

```
select SiteName, LastName, Id, Type, StartDate, min(StartTime), Duration
from mytable 
where RN  = 2
group by SiteName, LastName, Id, Type, StartDate,  Duration



SiteName    LastName    Id      Type    StartDate   StartTime   Duration    
--------    --------    --      ----    ---------   ---------   --------        
PK          Jones       284     iov     20171026    845         5       
PK          Jones       284     iov     20171113    845         5       
PK          Jones       284     iov     20171201    845         5       
PK          Jones       284     iov     20171206    845         5       
PK          Jones       284     iov     20171214    845         5       
PK          Jones       284     iov     20171215    845         5       
PK          Jones       284     iov     20171222    845         5
```

I want to return SiteName, LastName, Id, Type, StartDate, min(StartTime), Duration of each StartDate group when RN = 2. 
For example, my results should look like this:

```
SiteName    LastName    Id      Type    StartDate   StartTime   Duration    
--------    --------    --      ----    ---------   ---------   --------        
PK          Jones       284     iov     20171026    830         5       
PK          Jones       284     iov     20171113    740         5       
PK          Jones       284     iov     20171201    640         5       
PK          Jones       284     iov     20171206    840         5       
PK          Jones       284     iov     20171214    840         5       
PK          Jones       284     iov     20171215    840         5       
PK          Jones       284     iov     20171222    840         5
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Uh, your expected results don't match your query. They mostly contain records where RN = 1. Something does not add up here.

Comment: My expected results contain RN=1 because I want to return the min(StartTime) when there are at least 2 rows with the same StartDate

Comment: SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following SQL query.

```
SELECT SiteName, 
       LastName, 
       Id, 
       Type, 
       StartDate, 
       MIN(StartTime) StartTime, 
       Duration
  FROM mytable
 WHERE StartDate IN (SELECT StartDate
                       FROM mytable
                      WHERE RN = 2)
 GROUP BY SiteName, 
          LastName, 
          Id, 
          Type, 
          StartDate, 
          Duration
```

[Result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/75477/6)

```
SiteName    LastName    Id  Type    StartDate   StartTime   Duration
PK          Jones       284 iov     2017-10-26  830         5
PK          Jones       284 iov     2017-11-13  740         5
PK          Jones       284 iov     2017-12-01  640         5
PK          Jones       284 iov     2017-12-06  840         5
PK          Jones       284 iov     2017-12-14  840         5
PK          Jones       284 iov     2017-12-15  840         5
```

Comment: @Ferdinand-gasper The StartDate subquery needs to be further restricted by SiteName, LastName, Id, Type (i.e. corelated).  Otherwise dates from unrelated records (say:  LastName = 'Smith" and rn = 2) will be included for all groupings and not just the grouping of concern.

Comment: PERFECT! Thanks.